# Override Abp IdentityUser class property

Tags: c#, abp

I want to override column names in the DbContext as:

```
public DbSet<IdentityUser> Users { get; set; }

  builder.Entity<IdentityUser>(b =>
        {
            b.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasColumnName("FirstName");
            b.Property(x => x.Surname).IsRequired().HasColumnName("LastName");
        });
```

I created the migration, and the database gets the new name columns. But now I want to use those columns on my code, i.e. in a seeder, so if I try to use them as:

```
new IdentityUser(
                 ...
                )
                {
                   //Can't use FirstName and LastName
                    Name = adminUserName,
                    Surname = "surname",
                };
```

I can not use my new properties because IdentityUser got no override with my new column names. How can I override the columns?

I tried to add a class like:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        [Column("FirstName")]
        public override string Name { get; set; }

        [Column("LastName")]
        public override string Surname { get; set; }
    }
```

Then change the DbContext as:

```
   public DbSet<User> CustomUsers { get; set; }
   public DbSet<IdentityUser> Users { get; set; }

builder.Entity<IdentityUser>(b =>
            {
                b.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasColumnName("FirstName");
                b.Property(x => x.Surname).IsRequired().HasColumnName("LastName");
                b.HasOne(typeof(TimeZone))
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("TimeZoneId");
            });
```

And add the migration... this is generating a migration with Discriminator field

```
public partial class OverrideIdentityColumns : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "Discriminator",
                table: "AbpUsers",
                type: "nvarchar(max)",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: "");
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "Discriminator",
                table: "AbpUsers");
        }
    }
```

How can I override the values of the IdentityUser class to use FirstName and LastName keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Do this after the ConfigureIdentity function. Otherwise, there will be no change.